# What would you use to build a product listing plus filters as the suggested example?

Tags: ecommerce

I have been assigned the task to build a catalog of products / on-line shop

What technology would you use to create a product listing + left sidebar filters like this one?

http://www.sarenza.co.uk/men-lace-ups

Answer (score 2):

Well I'd use PHP / MYSQL / JQUERY / HTML / CSS combination. I've built serveral online shops like that.

The particular example you've given was built with ASP.NET, so that's another alternative. Another option would be Ruby (on Rails).

It depends on what you already know, all of the above are capable of doing what you want. Some don't like PHP because it's open source, but hey, even Facebook is built with php!